# JavaFX table is not displaying data

Tags: java, javafx

I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJABHGAJ) to write a JavaFX code to populate and display records in a table. The records can be multiple and the records are the objects of the LibraryMember class (provided below), but the table is not displaying the records. Please figure out what is wrong in my code?

```
private TableView<LibraryMember> table;
public ObservableList<LibraryMember> allMemberDataRecords = list;

/*
The data in the above list is in the following format:
[Member Info: ID: 1004, name: Ricardo Montalbahn, 641-472-2871 (501 Central, Mountain View, 94707), Member Info: ID: 1003, name: Sarah Eagleton, 451-234-8811 (42 Dogwood Dr., Fairfield, 52556), Member Info: ID: 1002, name: Drew Stevens, 702-998-2414 (1435 Channing Ave, Palo Alto, 94301), Member Info: ID: 1001, name: Andy Rogers, 641-223-2211 (5001 Venice Dr., Los Angeles, 93736)]
*/


table = new TableView();
table.setEditable(true);

TableColumn idCol = new TableColumn("Member Id");
idCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<LibraryMember, String>("memberId"));

TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<LibraryMember, String>("firstName"));

TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<LibraryMember, String>("lastName"));

TableColumn streetCol = new TableColumn("Street");
lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<LibraryMember, String>("lastName"));

TableColumn cityCol = new TableColumn("City");
cityCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<LibraryMember, String>("city"));

TableColumn stateCol = new TableColumn("State");
stateCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<LibraryMember, String>("state"));

TableColumn zipCol = new TableColumn("Zip");
zipCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<LibraryMember, String>("zip"));

TableColumn phoneCol = new TableColumn("Telephone");
phoneCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<LibraryMember, String>("telephone"));

table.setItems(allMemberDataRecords);
table.getColumns().addAll(idCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol, streetCol, cityCol, stateCol, zipCol, phoneCol);

final VBox vbox = new VBox();
vbox.setSpacing(5);
vbox.getChildren().add(table);
grid.add(vbox, 0, 1);

Scene scene = new Scene(grid);
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("library.css").toExternalForm());
setScene(scene);
```

**LibraryMember Class:**

```
package business;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;


import dataaccess.DataAccess;
import dataaccess.DataAccessFacade;

final public class LibraryMember extends Person implements Serializable {
    private String memberId;

    public LibraryMember(String memberId, String fname, String lname, String tel,Address add) {
        super(fname,lname, tel, add);
        this.memberId = memberId;       
    }


    public String getMemberId() {
        return memberId;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Member Info: " + "ID: " + memberId + ", name: " + getFirstName() + " " + getLastName() + 
                ", " + getTelephone() + " " + getAddress();
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2226197306790714013L;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Putting everything needed to reproduce the issue in the `start` method and posting posting the complete item type would be a good idea; make sure the logic for filling the data is also there and not as simple as it can get (=some hardcoded values), if you've verified this is not the issue. Right now I see a few ways this could go wrong with no way for us to tell which one applies...

Comment: @Agha Salman I'm not sure why are you doing this? ->  `public ObservableList<LibraryMember> allMemberDataRecords = list;` Is this what you have in the real code? Where the list is coming from? Please make sure that `list` has data to populate in the table.